# What does the y/2 do in this function that recursively finds a number raised to a certain power?

Tags: c++, recursion

I understand that dividing the power by 2 with each recursive call helps us approach the base case, but could someone explain the intuition behind why dividing the power by 2 in each recursive call works?  Thank you!

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y) 
{ 
    int temp; 
    if( y == 0) 
        return 1; 
    temp = power(x, y/2); 
    if (y%2 == 0) 
        return temp*temp; 
    else
        return x*temp*temp; 
}
```

Note: Function sourced from GeeksForGeeks

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code by hand? Try a simple example like `power(2,7)` and trace the execution of the program, it should make sense.

Comment: Because `x^y` equals `x^(y/2) * x^(y/2)` for even y and `x * x^(y/2) * x^(y/2)` for odd y. Here I'm using `^` to mean 'to the power of'. The code given is just those formulae translated to C++.